# Allocate values in respective variables

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Each row is wrongly allocated in his respective column. Is there a way to sort correctly and if there is not value, NA is included. Thanks in advance

```
df <- data.frame(
  price = c("1€", "1€", "2022-03-04", "4hr", "Iberia"),
  duration = c("2€", "1hr", "2022-01-02", "4hr", "Eurostart"),
  airline = c("3€", "1hr", "2022-01-03", "5min", "ITA"),
  dates = c("4€", "1hr 5min", "2022-01-03", "Air france", "Lufthansa")
)


desired_output <- data.frame(
  price = c("1€", "1€", "2€", "3€", "4€", "NA"),
  duration = c("1hr", "1hr", "1hr 5min", "4hr", "4hr", "5min"),
  airline = c("Air france", "Iberia", "Eurostart", "ITA", "Lufthansa", "NA"),
  dates = c("2022-03-04", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-03", "NA", "NA")
)
```

Comment: At a first glance, cleaning your messy data would require a lot of more or less manual work. IMHO the issue is that something went terribly wrong when reading the data. Hence I would suggest to go back to start and figure out how to read you data in a more tidy format instead of trying to clean it afterwards.

Comment: Do you think @stefan that I could create extra variables which goes to each variable and takes somes patterns. For example, in variable `price_x` , only rows with the **€** can be stored. In the variable `duration`, only rows with **hr** or **min** can be stored and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would go back to start and try to figure out why the data is read in a messy format. Be it as it is here is one option to clean your data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  price = c("1€", "1€", "2022-03-04", "4hr", "Iberia"),
  duration = c("2€", "1hr", "2022-01-02", "4hr", "Eurostart"),
  airline = c("3€", "1hr", "2022-01-03", "5min", "ITA"),
  dates = c("4€", "1hr 5min", "2022-01-03", "Air france", "Lufthansa")
)

df_mat <- as.matrix(df)

is_pattern <- list(
  price = grepl("\\€$", df_mat),
  duration = grepl("(hr|min)", df_mat),
  date = grepl("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$", df_mat)
)
is_pattern$airline <- !is_pattern$price  & !is_pattern$duration & !is_pattern$date

vec_list <- lapply(is_pattern, function(x) df_mat[x])

max_len <- max(lengths(vec_list))

vec_list <- lapply(vec_list, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x))))

as.data.frame(vec_list)
#>   price duration       date    airline
#> 1    1€      4hr 2022-03-04     Iberia
#> 2    1€      1hr 2022-01-02  Eurostart
#> 3    2€      4hr 2022-01-03        ITA
#> 4    3€      1hr 2022-01-03 Air france
#> 5    4€     5min       <NA>  Lufthansa
#> 6  <NA> 1hr 5min       <NA>       <NA>
```